# Is there a disavantage in rendering a pure html, css and a client side script like JS? versus php rendering a web page?

Tags: php, html

Most of i have read in book and tutorial most recommend that you render html,css and Js in Php.

Is there a disavantage in rendering a pure html, css and JS in a web design project?

it seem really very long file if i use Php to render a webpage versus html.

Comment: Sorry, in its current form it is questionable what you actually ask. What do you mean by "to render html in php"? The web client (browser) renders html into a visual representation, css and js are never rendered, only processed and may change how a page is rendered. If you refer to how a html page is constructed before being sent to the client, then I don't see why using php should be a (significantly) longer than static html. The most common reason to use php instead of html obviously is that you can create html pages in a dynamical way. This is not possible when using static html files.

Comment: The "length" of the PHP file is a non-logical concern. Brevity is nice, but there are far more important considerations. I would suggest using something like Symfony or Slim Framework instead of rolling your own front controller (are you thinking one giant `switch case` per page for example?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are talking about milliseconds here. Unless there's some really heavy
load on the server or some very complex scripts running, the users won't
be able to notice much of a difference. The page creation will still be
much faster than the transfer to the browser.

PHP is a server-side language and the use-case is a bit different. If you want to use PHP in your project, then use it. For example, if you want to query the database, get the output or do similar operators, you'll have to use PHP. Pure HTML alone can't do that.

> It seem really very long file if I use PHP to render a webpage versus html.

The length of the file is irrelevant here. It's the use-case that matters.

To answer your question, there's no harm if you create the page in pure HTML / Javascript alone but this may not work for some particular situations. There are occasions when pure HTML / JS alone can't do what you want (for example, querying the database). In such cases, use PHP. If you don't need to perform such actions, don't use it.

Comment: These are competing dictums: *To answer your question, **there's no harm if you create the page in pure HTML/Javascript alone**. But this **won't work in all cases**.*

Comment: @JaredFarrish: how about now? :)

Comment: Let's use an example: Jill, a Web Designer, contracts for US$500 to build a website for Sushi Su, a local restaurant. If that contract calls for: a homepage and about, menu, contact and directions pages, that could (conceivably) be a flat-file-based site. The menu may need to change (prices, offerings) every few months, Jill might charge US$50 to edit in minor changes. However, if the contract calls for a web-based ordering system and/or a menu that can be edited by Su, or a "daily special" that Su can add herself, the chances of this not including server-side interactivity diminish greatly.

Comment: The potential harm, then, is that complications are manifold that Jill has dramatically *limited* the capabilities of the site and priced her time at a point to where there is only *one option*. If the customer is not expecting this, the harm could affect her reputation, impose cost considerations the client may balk at paying, and otherwise generate a bit of rework and/or gross inefficiency. Static or flat-file-only sites work in some (limited) cases, but the underlying need is more relevant when pairing a solution to a request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will really make your code longer. However, you can use PHP framework which uses MVC design pattern that will help you separate your views from your logics. They also have template engine so instead of writing php codes in your views you just use brackets or {{ }} or whatever they use.